# Ionic App Deep Linking

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework, share

So I have managed to call my Ionic App with safari and chrome by calling `app/::` on my Ipad. This can be happened by following tutorial from Facebook Ios developer : `https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/{fb-app-id}/?platform=ios.`

The question is : how can i make `app://products/product` with the original ionic is `#/tab/products/product` to be called ? or can accomplish this.

the purpose is to share the link with its content on FB

I already follow the tutorial given but no luck

Thanks guys.. any help will be appreciated

Comment: Well if you pass the parameter you should be able to use the deep link listener method to simulate this by using the $state service and call $state.go to the state name with the required parameters

Comment: Will be great if you can supply me with the the codes, and thanks for the reply will search further with your info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally for deep linking on Ionic Platform i got this to read and make further improvements including the use of Facebook API for my deeper purpose

`https://www.sitepoint.com/working-with-the-facebook-api-in-a-cordova-app/`

as this image show

[for deep linking on Facebook app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6QsG.png)